# How much of a difference is my squid cache making?

Tags: linux, internet, cache, squid

I'm on an ADSL connection that has a bandwidth limit (I can download 100 gig per month). For a bit of a test I set up Squid as a transparent web proxy to capture all HTTP traffic and attempt to cache some of it.

Is there anything in Squid that lets me find out simple things like

"Clients requested 500 meg of stuff, the cache provided 150 meg of that content"

i.e I want to find out if the cache is actually doing anything useful.

I have the cachemgr.cgi running, but the data it provides is... difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [lots of squid cache log analyzers](http://www.squid-cache.org/Misc/log-analysis.html) available. Personally I used only `sarg` which is quite nice but not very fancy. It is shipped by various distributions.

Comment: I'll look at Sarg, it might be useful. I also remembered I have cacti running, so maybe that can make some graphs for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is a few years late, but noone has answered the simple command line tool   squidclient

```
squidclient mgr:info | grep "Hit Ratios"
```

should give you the info on hit percentages, then its a matter of working back from totals.

IE, a 60min Byte Hit Ratio of 20% and a total traffic of 100MB means 20MB was served by your squid proxy in the last hour.